# Como fazer um form afetar outro form no C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou criando um projeto em que terá certas configurações como notificações.Estas notificações ao serem escolhidas para poderem aparecer na barra de tarefas irão afetar outros forms.

Como o sistema é call center quando um analista desejar que as notificações sejam exibidas para o usuário através da barra de tarefa,elas irão aparecer para ele.

Como posso fazer com que um form afete os demais que estão por exemplo conectados á uma rede ?

Caso necessário irei postar o que já fiz até agora. E me desculpem caso esteja errado o formato desta pergunta pois sou novo no fórum.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, o q vc qr dizer com "afetar o form"? Coloque o seu código tbm.

Comment: Quando por exemplo um analista no aplicativo colocar para exibir notificações para os usuários,irá ocorrer de modificar o form dos usuários também,exibindo notificações.

Comment: Dê uma pesquisada sobre delegates e events, resolvi um problema parecido com isto, mas era dentro da mesma aplicação, agora se você quer notificar todas as pessoas que estão executando a aplicação, acho que você vai ter que ter um banco de dados para auxiliar as notificações

Comment: Siga a dica do @Robss70 e coloque parte do que você já fez para podermos analisar.